# Angsana New font overlaps in generated pdf file

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports

Angsana New font gets overlapped in JasperReports's report while generating the pdf.

I have added the Angsana ttf font file in the jasper and font-jar. The pdf is getting generated but some characters are getting overlapped.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the original text fragment?  What JasperReports version are you using?

Comment: I am using Jaspersoft Studio 6.4.3. Also if I am exporting the font through jasper, it is correctly printed. But if embedded in the custom-jasperreports-fonts (custom made jar of jasperreports-fonts.jar) this gets overlapped

Comment: It worked. angsa.ttf file added in the custom-jasperreports-fonts (custom made jar of jasperreports-fonts.jar) was of different size than the angsa.ttf font exported from jasper. when I replaced that with exported ttf file